# no me funciona el else en el atributo cumple_a

Tags: python, poo, formato-condicional

tengo un pequeño problema con mi codigo, lo que pasa es que quiero calcular la edad y dar un mensaje de cumpleaños, lo cual logro hacer perfectamente con mi el método cumple_a. pero el problema radica en que no cumple la condicion elif. siempre muestra como si cumpliera años asi las fechas sean distintas

````
d=int
m=int
a=int
fecha=(a,m,d)
d1=int
m1=int
a1=int
hoy=(a1,m1,d1)
from datetime import date 
class Humano(): #Creamos la clase Humano
    def __init__(self, edad, nombre,fecha,hoy): #Definimos el parámetro edad , nombre y ocupación
        self.edad = edad # Definimos que el atributo edad, sera la edad asignada
        self.nombre = nombre # Definimos que el atributo nombre, sera el nombre asig
        self.fecha=fecha #fecha de nacimiento 
        self.hoy=hoy#fecha de hoy
        #Creación de un nuevo método
    def presentar(self):
        presentacion = ("Hola soy {name}, mi edad es {age} ") #Mensaje
        print(presentacion.format(name=self.nombre, age=self.edad)) #Usamos FORMAT
    def cumplio_anios(self):
        self.edad=self.edad+1
        print("Feliz cumpleaños te deseamos a ti, {name}".format(name=self.nombre))
    def cumple_a(self):
        if fecha[0] and fecha[1]== hoy[0] and hoy[1]:
            self.edad=self.edad+1
            print("Feliz cumpleaños {name}".format(name=self.nombre),'cumples {year} años'.format(year=self.edad))
        else:
            print('hoy no cumples años, {name}'.format(name=self.nombre))
Persona1 = Humano(31, "Pedro",(1995,10,24),(2021,11,24)) #Instancia  
Persona1.presentar() 
Persona1.cumple_a()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El condicional estaba mal organizado, al poner dos condiciones iguales iguala variable a variable una a una y no dos a dos, a parte igualabas el año y el mes en vez del mes y el día al hacer referencia a fecha[0]  hacías referencia al año. Espero que te sirva. Un saludo.

```
d=int
m=int
a=int
fecha=(a,m,d)
d1=int
m1=int
a1=int
hoy=(a1,m1,d1)
from datetime import date 
class Humano(): #Creamos la 
clase Humano
  def __init__(self, edad, nombre,fecha,hoy): #Definimos el parámetro edad , nombre y ocupación
    self.edad = edad # Definimos que el atributo edad, sera la edad asignada
    self.nombre = nombre # Definimos que el atributo nombre, sera el nombre asig
    self.fecha=fecha #fecha de nacimiento 
    self.hoy=hoy#fecha de hoy
    #Creación de un nuevo método
  def presentar(self):
    presentacion = ("Hola soy {name}, mi edad es {age} ") #Mensaje
    print(presentacion.format(name=self.nombre, age=self.edad)) #Usamos FORMAT
  def cumplio_anios(self):
    self.edad=self.edad+1
    print("Feliz cumpleaños te deseamos a ti, {name}".format(name=self.nombre))
  def cumple_a(self):
    if self.fecha[1]== self.hoy[1] and self.fecha[2]== self.hoy[2]:
        self.edad=self.edad+1
        print("Feliz cumpleaños {name}".format(name=self.nombre),'cumples {year} años'.format(year=self.edad))
    else:
        print('hoy no cumples años, {name}'.format(name=self.nombre))
Persona1 = Humano(31, "Pedro",(1995,10,24),(2021,11,24)) #Instancia  
Persona1.presentar() 
Persona1.cumple_a()
```